# VMware Workstation Player snapshots

Tags: windows, gratis, backup, virtual-machine

I have several virtual machines in VMware Workstation 12 Player on my local computer, and I need to take snapshots of some of the machines from time to time. Unfortunately, the free version does not allow me to create snapshots.

Currently I have a batch script that just asks which machine I want to save and prompts for a snapshot name. Then the VM directory is copied into a *Snapshots* directory together with the VM name, a timestamp and the snapshot title.
This works but is uncomfortable, because I have to search for the correct snapshot folder, copy it, back up the currently running version and replace it with the snapshot every time I want to revert.

Is there any tool/software that comes with a nice interface to help me creating and loading snapshots? It should be free (as in "free beer" – open-source is not a requirement, but accepted) and run on Windows 7.